# ERROR - NG0204: Can't resolve all parameters for Auth: (?)

Tags: angular, firebase, web, firebase-authentication

While trying to add Firebase mobile otp based login in my angular code base I am getting this error .

I am using Angular version 14, Firebase: 9.17, @angular/fire: 7.5

This "Auth" in picture is coming from import { Auth } from '@angular/fire/auth';

and I have placed it in the providers array in the app.module.ts

Any help would be appreciated.

I believe this is related to the angular version, but I am not super sure.

Comment: in angular fire npm module it is stated that 7.4 module version is compatible with angular 14. don't think it would help, but worth trying for sure

Comment: btw, are you using pnpm? there could be an issue where different versions of `firebase` exist on runtime and everything breaks because of that